# Javascript PDF form Radio Button Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

I searched and couldn't find any results pertaining to javascript / PDF form applications so I apologize if there are actual results out there that I may have missed.

I have 5 radio buttons, all sycronized for if one is turned on, rest are turned off. I'm trying to enable, based on which is selected, for which form (Cells) to show on a pdf.

This is currently where I stand. The radio button for this script is set to mouse-up, and when turned on Text2 shows, but when a separate radio button is selected Text2 still shows. Only when I re-selected the first radio button does the Text2 disappear.

I'm looking to show only particular cells based on what radio button is selected, and the rest are hidden.

If someone could help lead me to a small example and I could apply from there. Thank you

```
if (this.getField("Text2").display == display.hidden)
{
this.getField("Text2").display = display.visible;
}
else
{
    this.getField("Text2").display = display.hidden;
}
```

edit: grammar
update: This is what i'm necessarily trying to accomplish

```
if (this.SELECTED("Choice4")){
this.getField("Text4").display = display.visible}
else{
this.getField("Text4").display = display.hiddenl}
```

update2: does not work either

```
if(document.getElementByI("Choice3").checked){
this.getField("Text4").display = display.visible}
else{
this.getField("Text4").display = display.hidden}
```

Comment: Can you post the form somewhere? Your code will toggle the field but I think you're triggering it in the wrong event. Without the form or more information, I can't be more specific. Also, given what you describe, I don't think you want radio buttons, checkboxes seem more appropriate. With radio buttons, once you select a one, one will always be selected until you reset the form.

Comment: Hi. Having one of the buttons selected would be OK. It would be OK to have something showing at all times,  I just want to be able to switch between forms using any method (even a dropdown would be appropriate)

Comment: If you just want to quickly switch between forms using the same document, I'm going to suggest you change your approach. Authoring multiple forms on the same page using hide/show is extremely difficult in Acrobat. The form authoring tool just wasn't engineered with overlapping fields in mind. Instead, consider creating each form as a "template" page and then spawn or remove the pages based on the selection in the dropdown which would need to exist on every template. Templates are essentially entire pages, including form fields, that can be shown or hidden through code.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is when toggling a button in a set of radio buttons (or checkboxes behaving as radio buttons) is to first hide all fields which could be shown, and then show the ones matching the selection.

This can be made a lot easier with hierarchical field names. All fields which can be shown or hidden have the same stem in their name, and the second element matches the option, as in

```
showfield.option1.myfield
```

with

```
this.getField("showfield").display = display.hidden
```

you make all fields being part of the showfield group hidden, and with

```
this.getField("showfield.option1").display = display.visible
```

you show all fields in the option1 group within the showfield group.

Comment: Is there a way to maybe code the forms directly? If I want to show only certain forms (text boxes, buttons, check boxes, etc) ONLY IF a major check box (i.e. FORM 1) is selected. So maybe I can individually code each form that if FORM 1 box is checked, it will be visible. If NOT check, it will change to hidden?

Comment: Absolutely… actually, the concept shown above is the key to successfully show/hide fields based on selection.